Adding a numeric value to character in an Insert statement
I would like to replace a character value with a character +Numeric value in an Insert statement e.g.
REPLACE(b.Tax, '.', '')  +  a.TaxR as TaxR
where tax is numerical value.
How can I do it?
Thank You.
